# twilio.min.js:77 WebSocket connection to 'wss://chunderw-vpc-gll.twilio.com/signal' failed: Error in connection establishment:

Tags: javascript, c#

twilio.min.js:77 WebSocket connection to 'wss://chunderw-vpc-gll.twilio.com/signal' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

Error: WSTransport socket error
Dashboard:453 WSTransport socket error

*I am trying to integrate twilio client and i am facing below issue. Any one can help?*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I solved it by adding the Google DNS to my network

> 8.8.8.8
>
> 8.8.4.4

Comment: this is not mentioned in Twilio Voice SDK(Js). How do I do this? Even singal wss shows as pending on my browser and I am unable to connect the call, it connects and disconnections with logs showing 'rejected by remote'. The remote phone is right next to me so no one's really rejecting it. Is is related to the signal wss?